# Prove that the integers $ (n+1)!+2, (n+1)!+3, (n+1)!+4, ... (n+1)!+(n+1) $ are all composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the following integers are composite numbers:
$ (n+1)!+2, (n+1)!+3, (n+1)!+4, ...(n+1)!+(n+1) $

I am not sure exactly where to start with this, so any help or hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ (n+1)! + k $ will have $ k $ as a factor, since $ \left ( n + 1 \right ) ! $ will include a factor of $ k $ ($ k \leq n + 1 $) and $ k $ is obviously divisible by itself. Therefore $ \left ( n + 1 \right )! + k $ will not be prime.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found it answered the question so that future viewers with your question are pointed to the correct answer. Outlined in the help tutorial.

Comment: (although the other answer is fine - pretty much exactly the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are of the form (n+1)! + r where r<= n+1.
Hence r divides all the above numbers

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that someone already posted an answer while i was writing mine.